# MySQL column encryption with Hibernate in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I need to encrypt data saved onto my DB. I am currently using spring and hibernate to save data.

I have looked at some materials and tried to implement the code, however, it has resulted in various generic errors, some of the material was not targeted to MySQL etc.

Here's the code that has got me furthest

```
@Column(name="disability_description")
@Length(max=500)
@ColumnTransformer(
        read =  "AES_DECRYPT(disability_description, 'mykey')",
        write = "AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'mykey')"
                )
private String disabilityDescription;
```

This, however, doesn't work as I get the following errors

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF9\x82u\x01\x99\x1A...' for column 'disability_description' at row 1
```

Please point in the right direction. I am lost. Also `mykey` doesn't point to anything, I just entered a random word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that your column is not of type BINARY:

Mysql Doc:

> AES_ENCRYPT() encrypts the string str using the key string key_str and
>   returns a **binary string** containing the encrypted output.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. 
Thank you for your time you got this spot on, I changed it to VARBINARY and voila! Happens all the time, spend all this time doing something and then it is so simple and right in front of you.

Thanks again